# How to add searchable field in Drupal 9 backend

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-9

In my Drupal 9 dashboard I can search different content based on following field:

[image]

I want to add one more field, let's suppose "name" field, where I want to search all names. How I can add one more field here?

Comment: This post featured a supplementary question that was added after an answer came in. Since that has now correctly been posted as a new question, I have rolled this one back. One question at a time please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a view and you can configure it. GoTo /admin/structure/views/view/content and add filters on the left bottom side.

Comment: I have one more question to ask.
In my react application I am using storybook and for stories I am using chromatic where all my images are published. I hav edit my question pls check if you can answer.